# Lenovo IdeaTab showing a screen with Chinese characters

Tags: lenovo, virus

I'm using a Lenovo IdeaTab S6000. As I was watching videos, suddenly my tablet turned off. The buttons did not work and I was unable to restore it or turned it on. On the display, there were exposed these Chinese characters as they were changing with the abbreviations WIFI, GPS and MMC.

[image]

What is this screen? Is this a virus? How to fix this?

Comment: That looks like a boot-loader menu for a factory reset but in Chinese.

Comment: It doesn't look like the bootloader or recovery menu ([screenshots](https://droidrecovery.com/lenovo-ideatab-s6000-recovery-mode/)). You may have entered some secret factory menu.

Comment: That is the factory self-diagnosis and test menu. It is designed for usage before shipment, therefore it is in Chinese). You can use Google translate on a second phone to translate the entries.